# How to find solution of complete elliptic integral of second kind?

Tags: hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals

How to prove the following?

$$E(k)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\cdot\,_2 F_1 \left(-1/2,1/2;1;k^2 \right),$$
where $E(k)$ denotes complete elliptic integral of the second kind, and $_2F_1(\cdot)$ is the Gauss Hypergeometric function.

Comment: Check if the link is helpful (equations (1), (2) and (3)): http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html

Comment: Welcome to mathematics SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to improve your equation. It'll be easier to read.

Comment: It follows immediately from definitions of elliptic integral and hypergeometric functions. What issue are you facing?